# Saltar inserción de un array de datos Laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

estoy haciendo una inserción de un array de datos mediante un excel, el archivo inserta los datos correctamente pero, quiero validar si en la inserción tiene el email vacío y si lo esta quiero que se salte el registro.

este es mi codigo

```
 public function model(array $row)
{
   //dd($row[1]);

    $idUser=user::updateOrCreate([
        'n_control'     => $row[0],
        'nombre'        => $row[1],
        'apellidop'     => $row[2],
        'apellidom'     => $row[3],
        'email'         => $row[4],
        'rol'           => 'ALUMNO',
    ]);

    $idAlumno = Alumno::updateOrCreate([      
        'carrera'   => $row[5],
        'id'        => $idUser->id,

    ]);


    
}
```

me gustaría omitir el registro y saltarme a insertar el siguiente si el email esta vacio

Muestro ejemplo de lo que se inserta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: así es, quiero insertar  datos que solo tengan email y son de N valores, solo que quería saber si hay algún comando que realice esta acción o se podria hacer de otra forma y el ejemplo seria algo así

Comment: edite la pregunta y adjunte una imagen de lo que se inserta desde mi excel

Comment: Puedes condicionar con un if a $row[4], dependiendo si es null o '' lo que recibes, `if($row[4]!='' || $row[4]!=null)` antes de insertar, eso deberia ayudarte.

Comment: Me parece que el row equivale a la columna del Excel, y la columna siempre sera la 4, no creo que haya problema, es Laravel Excel, sino me equivoco

Comment: array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(12560322)
  [1]=>
  string(5) "ANGEL"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "RAMIREZ"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "MENDOZA"
  [4]=>
  string(25) "edgar.grond1@hotmail.com1"
  [5]=>
  string(38) "INGENIERIA EN SISTEMAS COMPUTACIONALES"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(12560323)
  [1]=>
  string(7) "EDUARDO"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "PEREZ"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "ROBLES"
  [4]=>
  string(25) "edgar.grond1@hotmail.com2"
  [5]=>
  string(26) "INGENIERIA ELECTROMECANICA"
}

Comment: @BetaM sino me equivoco, ya que hace tiempo no uso, pero Laravel Excel a traves de la funcion model ya itera automaticamente todos los datos del excel, lo que faltaria seria la condicion, disculpa Edgar lograste colocar la condicion?.

Comment: me da error en el if

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123096/discussion-between-felipe-urcia-and-edgar-rodriguez-testa).

Comment: public function model(array $row)
{
//dd($row[1]);

$idUser=user::updateOrCreate([
if($row[4]!='' || $row[4]!=null){
'n_control' => $row[0],
'nombre' => $row[1],
'apellidop' => $row[2],
'apellidom' => $row[3],
'email' => $row[4],
'rol' => 'ALUMNO',
}
]);

$idAlumno = Alumno::updateOrCreate([
'carrera' => $row[5],
'id' => $idUser->id,

]);




}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disculpa la demora en contestar, no se si aun lo necesites, pero deberias simplemente validar si es que tu data llega o no llena.

```
{
//dd($row[1]);

if($row[4]!='' || $row[4]!=null){
$idUser=user::updateOrCreate([
'n_control' => $row[0],
'nombre' => $row[1],
'apellidop' => $row[2],
'apellidom' => $row[3],
'email' => $row[4],
'rol' => 'ALUMNO',
]);

$idAlumno = Alumno::updateOrCreate([
'carrera' => $row[5],
'id' => $idUser->id,

]);

}
```

Comment: Si me ayudó, te lo agradezco mucho